# JavaScript function parameter and scope

Tags: javascript, function, scope

I have done some tests with codes listed below:

```
function foo(x) {
    alert(y);
}
var y = 'I am defined outside foo definition';
foo();
```

The above code gives me an alert 'I am defined outside foo definition'.

Then another test:

```
function bar(x) {
    alert(x);
}
var x = 'I am defined outside foo definition';
bar();

function bar(x) {
    alert(x);
}
x = 'I am defined outside bar definition';
bar();
```

Both the above codes give me an alert 'undefined'.

So Why?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because when you declare the parameter x

```
function bar(x) { /*...*/ }
```

You are "hiding" the global variable x. You only have access to the parameter x

try passing in the global x

```
function bar(x) { alert(x); }
var x = 'I am defined outside bar definition';
bar(x); // here the x is the global x that we pass in
        // the function gets a reference to the global x
```

If we omit the parameter then the global x would become visible again

```
function baz() { alert(x); }
var x = 'global var';
baz(); // 'global var'
```

Note that global variables should be limited in good js applications.

Answer (score 6):

Because in both those cases you have a local scoped variable(the first parameter) in the function `bar` to which you are not passing any value. Since there is a local scoped variable it will not check the global scope to see whether such a variable exists.

In this case you need to pass the value to the parameter when `bar` is invoked

```
function bar(x) {alert(x);}
x = 'I am defined outside foo definition';
bar(x);
```

In the first case when you are using `y` inside `bar` there is no local scoped variable called `y` in `bar` so it looks at a parent scope to see whether such a variable exists if so that variables value is accessed that is how it is working

Answer (score 3):

If you define:

```
var y = 'I am defined outside foo definition';
```

It will be a global window variable (in case you are using js in a browser), which can be accessed 'globally' by calling:

```
window.y
```

If you use it inside a function, like:

```
function foo(x) {alert(y);}
```

It will still refer a global variable, because it is not shadowed by function parameters.

If you define a function as:

```
  function foo(y) {alert(y);}
```

Then `y` is being shadowed by function parameter (which is btw an alias for `arguments[0]`). Which means that all references to variable `y` inside this function will refer the parameter variable, not the global one. So for example:

```
var y = 'I am defined outside foo definition';
function foo(y) { y = 'something';}
alert(y);
```

will display *I am defined outside foo definition*.

**Edit:**
If you have a function:

```
function bar(x) {
    alert(x);
}
```

and you try to call it using  `bar()` then function parameter parameter `x` shadows global variable `x`. JS engine will look for local variable `x` and it will not be found - which means you will get `undefined` message in your alert.