# Function parameter scope in javascript

Tags: javascript

What is the scope of function parameter in Javascript

```
var greetFunc = function(name){
var something;
}

console.log("Hello" +name);
console.log(something);
```

I understand the scope of something is just inside the function, it will not exist outside that.
But what about name. Why the value is blank for name variable.

Comment: What do you see? What did you expect to see?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30748819/javascript-function-parameter-and-scope

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript function parameter and scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30748819/javascript-function-parameter-and-scope)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referencing `name` outside the function doesn't throw an error like you would expect because it is actually a global variable in every page, part of the global `window` object.  Typing `name` is the same as `window.name`.

The `something` variable causes an error because it hasn't been defined yet.  However, the name variable doesn't cause any problems because it is blank by default, at least in Chrome.  You are correct that variables created in a function don't exist outside it.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name for details.

Comment: Agreed, why the downvote(s)? In the OPs example, someone who didn't realize that about the `name` variable (I didn't) would be wondering why a `ReferenceError` was not being thrown on the `console.log("Hello" +name)`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This fact answered my question

Answer (score 2):

The parameter `name` is similar to declaring a variable `name` at the top of the function.

So the scope of a parameter is the function it is a part of.